# github-pages cname

Tags: gulp, github-pages, cname

Есть домен и привязанный к нему репозиторий [github-pages](/questions/tagged/github-pages), перенес весь проект на [gulp](/questions/tagged/gulp), и теперь при попытки зайти на сайт выдает 404.

Подключил `gulp-gh-pages`, создал таск, но сайт все равно не открывается.

Как починить?